# Android make POST request with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to make my first POST request to make the user login using retrofit library, but it's not working and i don't understand why. If i make a GET request it works, but with POST something gone wrong and i don't understand why. **My API run on localhost webserver**
My code of the LoginService:

```
private const val BASE_URL = "http://localhost:10000/api/"


/**
* Build the Moshi object that Retrofit will be using, making sure to add the Kotlin adapter for
* full Kotlin compatibility.
*/
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
   .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
   .build()



/**
* Use the Retrofit builder to build a retrofit object using a Moshi converter with our Moshi
* object.
*/
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
   .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
   .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
   .build()



interface LoginApiService {
   @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
   @POST("login")
   suspend fun makeLogin(@Body usr: User): LoginResponse
}


/**
* A public Api object that exposes the lazy-initialized Retrofit service
*/
object LoginApi {
   val retrofitService : LoginApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(LoginApiService::class.java) }
}
```

code of the LoginResponse class

```
data class LoginResponse(
   val token: String,
   val expiration: Date,
   val role: Int)
```

code of the User class:

```
data class User(
    val mail: String,
    val pw: String
) : Parcelable
```

Code of the ViewModel that make the request:

```
private fun makeLogin(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val usr = User(email, password)
                val rsp = LoginApi.retrofitService.makeLogin(usr)         
                _isLogged.value = true
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                _status.value = LoginStatus.ERROR
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to solve this please? it seems that the request it's not sended.
my retrofit call generate this error in logcat in the try-catch block

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.ticketapp.network.LoginResponse
       for method LoginApiService.makeLogin
```

Comment: Do you have internet permission declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @VictorCold yes, and all the gradles

Comment: You can try to add @Parcelize annotation to the User class. I'm not sure if that will solve the issue, but AFAIK it's not enough to just inherit from Parcelable.

Comment: but i already have @parcelize

Comment: Then you need to check your rsp value with logcat or debugger. By the response code and body/errorBody we can say more. Or maybe response doesn't even come, then we need to know what kind of exception is thrown.

Comment: @VictorCold i update the asnswer with the error i get in logcat

Comment: Probably it's because your "expiration" field is of Date type. Basically, JSON only supports primitive fields. I guess in your case you can try to change Date to String or Long. Depends on how you return it from your server.

Comment: @VictorCold yes i return a json and the expiration is a string

Comment: @VictorCold at the end it works, but sometimes the server is unreachable i don't know why

Comment: how do you know it's unreachable? Do you get some exception?

Comment: @VictorCold yes sometimes i get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 10000) from /10.0.2.16 (port 53078) after 10000ms

Comment: Oh, that's default Retrofit timeout - 10sec. You can fix it like this: 

`val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            val retrofit  = Retrofit.Builder()
                ...
                .client(client)
                .build()`

Comment: @VictorCold can you post an answer with the code?

Comment: haha, sure, it looks too bad in the comment

Comment: Change localhost to real ip address of your server. Change `expiration` type to `String` or make custom date adapter(converter). Try to print `Exception` when making login request.

Comment: @Bek i solve the problem.. but how can i change localhost to real ip adress if it runs on my localhost?

Comment: If you use windows, open cmd then type `ipconfig` look for `IPv4 Address` under `Ethernet adapter Ethernet:`.

Comment: @Bek and after that i put my ip in the url? Like http://20.20.20.20:1000/api ?

Comment: If your `IPv4 Address` is `20.20.20.20` then yes. Have you replaced? Is it working?

Comment: yes i get `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /20.20.20.20 (port 10000) from /10.0.2.16 (port 39100) after 10000ms`

Comment: @VictorCold if i open the url from chrome in the emulator it works, if i use the same url in the code with retrofit i get the error above

Comment: @azziza432 that's weird, because 10sec is default timeout. Did you increase it as I show in my answer?

Comment: yes, i don't know why but  the request work if i open chrome://inspect/#devices and click reload on the google chrome page opened in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Retrofit's timeout is 10sec. You can fix it like this:

```
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        val retrofit  = Retrofit.Builder()
            ...
            .client(client)
            .build()
```

Here I set it to 30secs, but you can use any number and TimeUnit you want.

**UPD**:

You can store Retorfit builder in a separate file like this:

```
interface WebService {
    companion object {

        fun <T> build(clazz: Class<T>): T {
        
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                ...
                .build()

            val retrofit  = Retrofit.Builder()
                ...
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(clazz)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have multiple ApiService interfaces. And use them like this:

```
val myApiService = WebService.build(MyApiServiceInterface::class.java)
myApiService.myRequestFunction()
```

Comment: thank you. Now i have the retrofit builder, the API and the service in the same file. Do you know how to make only one file with the retrofit builder and call it by each service? Because i'll make a lots of services

Comment: for some reason today it doesn't work... i get `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:10000` and i don't change anything from yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Into your application tag in manifest